# Find the index value of first empty row in Data frame pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a sheet using pandas. After reading the sheet, I am getting an empty row between the values.

So, I need to find the index value of that row and delete all the rows below that, then make a new data-frame.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

import pandas as pd

from pandas import ExcelWriter

pathbook = open_workbook("S:\\1. DIRECTORY MASTER\\FINANCIAL RESEARCH\\Data 
Initiative - PROJECTS\\Market Rollout\\"
                     "Modified Files\\2016\\2016A-3032 - CA.xlsx")
pathbook_sheet = pathbook.sheet_by_name("1-Rollout")

file = "S:\\1. DIRECTORY MASTER\\FINANCIAL RESEARCH\\Data Initiative - 
PROJECTS\\Market Rollout\\" \
   "Modified Files\\2016\\2016A-3032 - CA.xlsx"

for rowidx in range(pathbook_sheet.nrows):
    row = pathbook_sheet.row(rowidx)
    for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell.value == "Canadian Market":
            print("Sheet Name:", pathbook_sheet.name)
            print("Row Number:", rowidx)
            CADvalue = int(rowidx)
            CADvalue += 1

print(CADvalue)
reading_book = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="1-Rollout", 
skiprows=CADvalue, index_col=0).iloc[:12]

write = ExcelWriter("Final" + ".xlsx")
reading_book.to_excel(write, 'Sheet1', index=False)
write.save()
```

The example output in the excel file i am getting

`Sales            2016      2017    2018    2019    2020    2021
 Units Sold        0          0      0       4       14      37
 Unit Sale Price  1285      1285    1285    1285    1285    1285
 Unit Profit      4000      4000    4000    4000    4000    4000

 Rest of the World Market`

So there is an empty row between the last 3 rows

Comment: Can you show data and expected output?

Comment: What is empty? `0`? `NaN`? ` `?

Comment: @ScottBoston it done in the edit

Comment: @sidsoni I still can't see what the empty row looks like. Is it just empty strings?

Comment: @Scotty1- It is just an empty row in the excel sheet with no values in it - like a blank line and when i print the data-frame it shows the "nan" in every column.

Answer (score 1):

```
#First, find NaN entries in first column
blank_row_bool = reading_book.iloc[:,1].isna()
#Next, get index of first NaN entry
blank_row_index =  [i for i, x in enumerate(blank_row_bool) if x][0]
#Finally, restrict dataframe to rows before the first NaN entry
reading_book = reading_book.iloc[:(blank_row_index-1)]
```

Or, in a single line:

```
reading_book = reading_book.iloc[:([i for i, x in 
enumerate(reading_book.iloc[:,1].isna()) if x][0]-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what empty means. If it is just an empty string, as in `''`, the code to find the index would be:

```
empty = ''
idx_first_empty_row = reading_book.index[reading_book.iloc[:, 0] == empty][0]
```

This works if the first column is empty. If for example "empty" means `NaN`, then replace the line with:

```
idx_first_empty_row = reading_book.index[np.isnan(reading_book.iloc[:, 0])]
```

This works if the `dtype` of the rows is any numeric numpy type, like `np.float64`.

If the `dtype` is not any numpy numeric type, try the following:

```
idx_first_empty_row = np.where(reading_book.iloc[:, 0].isnull().values == True)
```

You can also, depending on the types of data in your rows, try this:

```
idx_first_empty_row = reading_book.index[reading_book.iloc[:, 0].isnull().values]
```

Comment: if i do with empty = ' ' the i get an following error.
  File "C:/Users/s.soni/PycharmProjects/marketdatarollout/Test2.py", line 27, in <module>
    idx_first_empty_row = reading_book.index[reading_book.iloc[:, 0] == empty]
  File "C:\Users\s.soni\PycharmProjects\marketdatarollout\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 879, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)
  File "C:\Users\s.soni\PycharmProjects\marketdatarollout\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 818, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: But if i try with empty = np.nan the i get the following result by printing print(idx_first_empty_row).  The result is - Float64Index([], dtype='float64')

Comment: You should improve your formatting. But considering your problem: Could you please post the *content* of your empty line? The problem is exactly what I was asking before: What does the "empty" row look like? Is it filled with empty strings, zeros or `NaN`?

Comment: It is just an empty row in the excel sheet with no values in it - like a blank line and when i print the data-frame it shows the "nan" in every column.

Comment: Ahhhh, so it is `NaN` values... Ok, one second.

Comment: yup ... Thanks for you help ... really appreciate it ... waiting for your answer

Comment: Now i am getting this - Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64')
 but i want the row number this contains ....

Comment: Did you try all of my solutions? It strongly depends on the kind of data in your rows. You should perhaps try to find out the type of your data by `type(reading_book[idx, 0])` where `idx` is the index to the first empty row. And also post the empty row content with `reading_book[idx, 0]`.

Comment: oh no it is getting too complicated. I tried every method which you have in answer . But id does not give me the row number.

Comment: If i do this idx_first_empty_row = reading_book.index[np.isnan(reading_book.iloc[:, 0])]  then the result is - Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64')

Comment: if i do idx_first_empty_row = np.where(reading_book.iloc[:, 0].isnull().values == True) then the result is - (array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int64),)

Comment: if i do idx_first_empty_row = reading_book.index[te.iloc[:, 0].isnull().values] then the result is if i replace te.iloc with reading_book.iloc - Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64')

Comment: I'd need to know what your data looks like to be able find your error. But this is up to you. Just try to find the `type` of the data stored in your `DataFrame` and the use this information solve your problem. Two last possible solutions I can give to you: replace `iloc[:, 0]` with `iloc[:, 1]` or `iloc[:, 2]`, for example: `idx_first_empty_row = reading_book.index[reading_book.iloc[:, 1].isnull().values]`.

Comment: To find the type of data a dataframe contains i have to do this - type(reading_book[idx_first_empty_row , 0]) or what ?

Comment: If THIS does not work, also try replacing `iloc[:, 0]` with `iloc[1:, 1]` or `iloc[1:, 2]`.

Comment: To find the type of data a dataframe contains i have to do this - type(reading_book[idx_first_empty_row , 0]) or what ?

Comment: For the columns use `reading_book.dtypes` and for the empty row `reading_book[idx_first_empty_row , 0].dtypes`, or use `type()`.